# How to make an upload method for a large file to Yandex Cloud Serverless function to be called on it?

Tags: file-upload, cloud, object-storage, yandex-api

So I want to have no personal server infrastructure. I want to have a HTTP API roun
t a user can upload a file into (2GB+) so that:

1. File would be stored to object storedge for 3 days
2. A serverless function would be called on it

So how to make an upload method for a large file to Yandex.Cloud Serverless function to be called on it?

So I need something similar to [this AWS sample](https://moduscreate.com/blog/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-a-serverless-framework/) for YC

Comment: This is tagged with boto3... Please remove.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on request size that Yandex Cloud Serverless Function could handle. It is **3.5MB**. So you won't be able to upload **2Gb**.

There is a workaround — upload the file directly to Object Storage using a [pre-signed link](https://cloud.yandex.com/en/docs/storage/concepts/pre-signed-urls). To generate the link, you'll need [AWS-like credentials](https://cloud.yandex.com/en/docs/iam/concepts/authorization/access-key) from Yandex Cloud.
Passing them to the client side is not safe, so it would be better to generate the link on the server (or Serverless Function) and return it to the client.

[Here is the tutorial](https://cloud.yandex.com/en/docs/storage/concepts/presigned-post-forms) covering the topic.